# reduce two total number of notes with one payment

Tags: php, mysql

i have case like, i have 2 note, first have total 100.000, second 50.000.
i pay 120.000. so i want first note is become 0. and second note become 30.000. 
which he paid first until 0 and then next. i was try with for, and foreach to update.
this part of my code

```
$query      = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DCTN_NBR) as DCTN_NBR, SUM(TND_AMT) as TND_AMT, GROUP_CONCAT(ORD_NBR_RT) as ORD_NBR_RT FROM $RTL.RTL_STK_DCTN WHERE DEL_NBR = 0";
// echo $query;
$result     = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $totdctnamt =  $row['TND_AMT'];
   // this result is total of paid = 120.000
}


foreach ($PrnNbr as $index => $PrnNbrStrs) 
    {
     $querystknote  = " SELECT TOT_AMT FROM $RTL.RTL_STK_HEAD WHERE ORD_NBR =".$PrnNbr[$index];
            $resultstknote = mysqli_query($connect, $querystknote);
            $rowstknote    = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstknote);
            $rowstknote['TOT_AMT'];
            // this result from 2 note 100.000 and 50.000
            $querytotrem  = " UPDATE $RTL.RTL_STK_HEAD SET TOT_REM = 0 WHERE ORD_NBR =".$PrnNbr[$index];
            // echo $querytotrem;
    }
```

now how to update first nota to 0 and the rest of pay first note to pay second note

Comment: I understood that `$totdctnamt` has the value `120,000` but which variable contains the notes `100,000` and `50,000` ? Is it `$rowtknote['TOT_AMT']`?

Comment: yes, it $rowtknote['TOT_AMT'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, always decrement your total and set the current note to zero if current note is less than the total.

Until total becomes less than the current note amount, then do the other way around:  set note amount = note - amount, and update total.

```
foreach ($PrnNbr as $index => $PrnNbrStrs) 
{
 $querystknote  = " SELECT TOT_AMT FROM $RTL.RTL_STK_HEAD WHERE ORD_NBR =".$PrnNbr[$index];
        $resultstknote = mysqli_query($connect, $querystknote);
        $rowstknote    = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstknote);

        $note = $rowstknote['TOT_AMT'];   // assuming this will be 100,000 then 50,000
        if($totdctnamt>=$note) {
          $totdctnamt -= $note;      //reduce the total amount
                                     // it was 120k
                                     // now it is 120k-100k = 20k
          $note = 0;
        } else {
           $note -= $totdctnamt;     // the second iteration, 
                                     // note is 50k, and total is 20k
                                     // so note will be 50k-20k = 30k

          $totdctnamt = 0;           // to avoid other notes being affected

        }

        // finally, we update the table
        $querytotrem  = " UPDATE $RTL.RTL_STK_HEAD SET TOT_REM = $note WHERE ORD_NBR =".$PrnNbr[$index];
        // echo $querytotrem;
}
```

Comment: why when i change the value like. 2 of notes is note a = 100.000 and note b = 50.000. when i pay with 132.000. note b = 0 and note a become = 30.000. it should be 18.000. 132.000 - 50.000 = 82.000 to pay 100.000 = 18.000

Comment: what u mean. i dont understand.

Comment: when i pay with 132.000. the echo result is . 70.000 $totdctnamt and 30.000 for $note

Comment: 50.000 and  100.000

Comment: sorry i miss something. it worked well. thank u ahmad. @Ahmad

Comment: @BenyBondBanjarnahor do you still need help?